# Qt : setGeometry not resize at the launchning of the app

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I'm working for a project in my degree and I have a problem with the GUI.

I have tested the placement of the differents widgets on a separated project to simplify the code I try.

Here is my problem: 
I have created an overloaded `resizeEvent` to resize all my widgets. It works great, except for one thing:

After the launch of my testprogram, the widgets are not well-sized, I need to manually resize the window one time to force the resizement, even if the `setGeometry` calls are in the constructor like in the following code.

**.h**

```
MainWindow.h
-------------
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QGroupBox>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void resizeEvent ( QResizeEvent * event );

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    QGroupBox *g1;
    QGroupBox *g2;
    QPushButton *but2;
    QGridLayout *lay;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    this->lay = new QGridLayout();
    this->g1 = new QGroupBox("g1");
    this->g2 = new QGroupBox("g2");
    this->but2 = new QPushButton("But2");
    this->lay->addWidget(g1, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    this->lay->addWidget(but2, 0, 1, 1, 1);
    this->lay->addWidget(g2, 1, 0, 1, 2);
    this->g1->setBaseSize(60, 60);
    this->g2->setBaseSize(60, 60);

    this->ui->centralWidget->setLayout(lay);
    this->ui->centralWidget->setMinimumSize(100, 100);

    this->but1->setHidden(true);

    this->g1->setGeometry(5, 1, (this->ui->centralWidget->width())55, (this->ui->centralWidget->height())-83);
    this->but2->setGeometry(this->g1->width()+10 , 6, 40, (this->ui->centralWidget->height())-88);
    this->g2->setGeometry(5, this->g1->height()+5, (this->ui->centralWidget->width())-10, 70);
 }

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::resizeEvent ( QResizeEvent * event )
{
    this->g1->setGeometry(5, 1, (this->ui->centralWidget->width())-55, (this->ui->centralWidget->height())-89);
    this->but2->setGeometry(this->g1->width()+10 , 6, 40, (this->ui->centralWidget->height())-88);
    this->g2->setGeometry(5, this->g1->height()+5, (this->ui->centralWidget->width())-10, 70);
}
```

I am trying to find a solution so that the widgets are well sized from the beginning

*UPDATE* Here are two pictures:

Before resize

[image: before resize]

After resize

[image: after resize]

The problem is that when there is nothing inside, the QGroupBox just take the size of the button next to it, I would like it to be larger from the beginning

Comment: I would strongly suggest to not overwrite the `resizeEvent`, saw this throughout a large project and it led to all kinds of problems. Instead try to achieve the desired look completly through layouts and spacers which is usually possible and much smoother in the end. If you'd include screenshots of initial and desired look someone might be able to help you on that as well.

Comment: i agree but i don't think the problem here is the resizeevent cause it works well when i resize my window. I have overwrited it because the size of my differents layout depends on which of them are set hidden or visible. The problem i have here is that at the launching of the app, it appears that the setGeometry is not executed even when it's a the end of the constructor. I tried to add some lines like QCoreApplication::processEvent or widget.update for all the widgets in the windows but nothing happens.

Comment: Yes but it is still an XY problem. The geometry of the widgets depend on other widgets which means everything has to be painted once before you can resize it I would think. So I would find another way around this which should give you less of a headache.

Comment: Thanks for your time and your replies, i have upload pictures to show in details what i try to do. The second QGroupBox have a fixedSize and the fisrt one need to fill the rest of the place available

Comment: Try to setGeometry in the showEvent. In the constructor the windows get constructed and will be initialized later which alters the geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `setGeometry` you should use the stretch-factor when adding the widgets to the layout (and maybe in resizeEvent() too) , like...

```
int col = 0, row = 0;
int stretch = 100 * (this->ui->centralWidget->width()-55.0) / this->ui->centralWidget->width();
this->lay->setColumnStretch( col, stretch );
stretch = 100 * (this->ui->centralWidget->height())-89.0) / this->ui->centralWidget->height();
this->lay->setRowStretch( row, stretch );
```

same way for the other widgets.